# How can i store a session live for next work?

Tags: iphone

I m new in iPhone development. i have a problem , i m using bluetooth connectivity in my application. it works good for message sending but when i want to send other data from other class using same session the session value does not go in next class.

Can any body tell me how can i store the same session for next data sending.

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a session object in app delegate, assign it current session value and use this session any where in app when you need.